# АВЛ-деревья на pascal

Tags: pascal

Здравствуйте! Помогите реализовать задачу на Pascal.Нужно завести АВЛ-дерево и организовать в нем действие по вставке элементов .

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как вопроса не по теме, потому что за других задачи не решают.

Comment: Что вы уже сделали, и с чем возникла проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Чем вам не подошли алгоритмы, представленные во всемирной сети? Вот, например, вот эти два, что я нашел за 1 минуту? http://saod.narod.ru/saod3/List013.html и 
http://www.borlpasc.narod.ru/docym/stryctyr/avl.htm